# If $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are Gaussian, and $E[X|Y,Z]$ is linear in $Y,Z$, does it mean that $(X,Y,Z)$ is Gaussian?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, gaussian

Let  $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be Gaussian random variables that are not independent. This does not imply that $(X,Y,Z)$ is a Gaussian vector. But if we add the conditions that $E[X|Y,Z]$ is a linear function of $Y,Z$, i.e, $E[X|Y,Z]=a+bY+cZ$ for some real numbers $a,b,c$, does that mean that $(X,Y,Z)$ is a Gaussian vector ?

The converse is true: If $(X,Y,Z)$ is Gaussian, then $E[X|Y,Z]$ is a linear function of $Y,Z$.

Comment: What if $X=Y=Z$ ? Then $E[X|Y,Z]=X=Y=Z$ and $(X,Y,Z)$ is not a Gaussian vector because its covariance matrix is degenerate.

Comment: What if $X$ is independent of $Y$ and $Z$, but $Y$ and $Z$ have some funky dependence that makes $(Y,Z)$ not jointly Gaussian?

Comment: @RobertIsrael by not independent I mean there is no way to factorize their joint distribution at all. So $X$ cannot be independent of the rest for example.

Comment: @KurtG. Good point. Do you have another counter-example? If that's the only case, the result is still interesting.

Comment: @KurtG. if $Z$ is normally distributed, then $(Z,Z,Z)$ is Gaussian vector.

Comment: @W.Volante note that KurtG's does not provide a counter-example. Alas, not in the usual sense of a Gaussian vector. Maybe you want a non-degenerated Gaussian vector. In that case, it should be obvious: you can take $X$ to be a linear combination of $Y$ and $Z,$ and these two independent normal Gaussians. Now, you said something about non-independence, and that is ambiguous (did you mean joint? every pair? something else?)

Comment: @WilliamM. any pair is dependent, so there is no independence at all, so for instance $Y$ cannot be independent from $Z$

Comment: @W.Volante easy, take $X = aY + bZ,$ and $(Y, Z) = u(N_1, N_2),$ where $u$ is linear, and $(N_1, N_2)$ is standard normal in 2-dimensions. Choose $u$ to make $(Y,Z)$ not independent. In this way, the triplet $(X,Y,Z)$ is a degenerated Gaussian vector with $E(X \mid Y, Z) = aY+bZ.$ Now, if you allow degenerated Gaussian vectors, we still have to think a bit.

Comment: @WilliamM. the goal is to obtain something that is not Gaussian (regardless of degeneracy) or to prove that it has to be Gaussian (including degenerate Gaussian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a triple of random variables $(X,Y,Z)$ such that each of the components $X$, $Y$,  and $Z$ are individually gaussian but the three of them are not jointly gaussian. Further, the conditional expectation $E[X|Y,Z]=Z$, a  linear function of $Y,Z$.

Let $U$ be a standard gaussian, let $V$ be independent of $U$ such that $P(V=1)=P(V=-1)=1/2$, let $Z=U$, let $Y=UV$, let $X=Z$.
Then $E[X|Y,Z] = Z$, which is a linear function of the pair $Y,Z$.
Clearly $X$ and $Z$ are standard gaussian.  Since the distribution of $U$ is symmetric about $0$, the distribution of $U$ is the same as that of $-U$, and so is the distribution of $Y=UV$.

Comment: I was just building a counter-example like that, I was taking $Y = Z$ instead of $X = Z$ (so it didn't quite work) but I guess I would have landed in the same exactly sooner or later.

Comment: My Swiss army knife has a $(Z,\pm Z)$ for $Z\sim N(0,1)$ blade,  for use in cases like this.